# Delete data from linked server via Openquery takes a long time

Tags: sql-server

I have a problem with deleting record on linked server, I tried both of the command below.

```
DELETE OPENQUERY (SRT, 'SELECT * FROM DP.STENCIL_LABEL');

DELETE FROM OPENQUERY (SRT, 'SELECT * FROM DP.STENCIL_LABEL');
```

15 minutes passed by it still won't finish so I cancel the execution.

I have around 85k record on that table, meanwhile inserting same amount of data to the same table via `OPENQUERY` only takes less than 2 minutes.

Any help?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are retrieving all data *first* and *then* deleting it. Why not delete it directly with a `DELETE FROM` or `TRUNCATE TABLE` statement?

Also, if your server is linked, you can specify the table from the linked server, no need for `openquery()`.

Try this:

```
truncate table SRT.YourDatabase.DP.STENCIL_LABEL;
```

Comment: Well, it's part of my stored procedure, delete all data and re-insert the new one and since the origin of data are from sqlserver, so I don't delete it directly.